# Mass convert MySQL data entries into custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, mysql

I have a MySQL table with about 500 rows of entries each containing: title, author, series, and series number.

Would anyone know how to mass convert the data into (1 entry per post) custom post type with title becoming post title, author and series as separate custom hierarchical taxonomies, and series number as a custom meta?

I'm planning to change from a simple MySQL database management system into a site in a WP MS installation.

Comment: post the table structure, maybe someone can help you with a code snippet

Comment: @OneTrickPony The table only has 4 fields: Title, Author, SeriesName and SeriesNum. The first 3 fields are type varchar(255) and SeriesNum is int(255). If there's anything else you need to know, ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method :

1. Export your SQL data and make a CSV
   file out of it
2. Parse that CSV file in
   a PHP script and put the data into an array
3. Parse the array and for each row, insert the values into WP

You will need the following functions to insert the data into WP :

1. [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to create and insert post data (title, content, etc.)
2. [wp_insert_term()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) to create the taxonomies terms and [wp_set_post_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms) to set them for each post
3. [update_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) to insert the custom field data of your posts

I suggest before doing all that you register the custom post type and taxonomies you are going to use in WP.

Comment: SQL to CSV to PHP seems unnecessary, just select the data from the source database and loop over the results, inserting each record straight into WP.

Comment: @Milo, yes you're right. SQL->CSV export may only be useful if the new site is on a different server and remote connect is not possible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no good at coding such things. It goes way beyond my meager PHP "skills". Would it be possible for you to lend a hand on details?

Answer (score 0):

Quick tips, as mike23 suggest export the table as CSV, the use the plugin [CSV Importer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-importer/other_notes/) to import data back in wp. Read the docs on the plugins page.